# How to change encrypted volume password on command line?

Tags: macos, time-machine, password, encryption

Disk util shows the encrypted disk I am using for time machine with the following info:

[image: disk-info]

But the Menu entry "file -> Change Password" is greyed out. Tried to turn to the command line, I found this [instructions](https://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-change-an-encrypted-volumes-password-in-os-x), and the first part works nicely:

```
> diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group DDE89BDF-9537-45FF-A786-697E828EB040
    =========================================================
    Name:         egmac2.bak
    Status:       Online
    Size:         2000021315584 B (2.0 TB)
    Free Space:   9392128 B (9.4 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume DFEAFE30-FF0B-417B-B845-7C0A283FB4D4
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk2s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     2000021315584 B (2.0 TB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 0A741FD9-F957-4188-B1D9-233145A76ABF
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
        |                        Passphrase Required
        |                        Accepts New Users
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 253049D8-C1A5-41B1-A9C5-788AA41E0157
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk3
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          1999659597824 B (2.0 TB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               egmac2.bak
            Volume Name:           egmac2.bak
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

But then:

```
> diskutil cs passwd 253049D8-C1A5-41B1-A9C5-788AA41E0157 -oldpassphrase whatever -newpassphrase whattheheck
diskutil: did not recognize coreStorage verb "passwd"; type "diskutil coreStorage" for a list
```